# Is there any way to use python's pyparsing module in multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

Our project code needs to parse many different strings using pyParsing. Each string takes ~1 second to parse but done sequentially they take over a minute.

When I try to use threads to do them in parallel, the threads seem to wait for each other and it actually takes longer than just doing it without threads.

Is there a way to use pyParser in multiple threads in a way that is truly parallel? Would it work to allocate new parser instances each time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the global interpreter lock (GIL) in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython)

Comment: Oh no. That's terrible. Is there any way to do (true) multi-threading at all in Python? I don't thing the multi-process option is worth it just for this. Do you know if pypy will do it?

Comment: pypy has a GIL: https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-pypy-have-a-gil-why

Comment: Multithreading works if you are IO-bound or if you use code that is written in compiled languages and which releases the GIL, for example numpy. Otherwise, just throw a `multiprocessing.Pool` at the problem